# jquery autocomplete textbox when it starts with a special character like @

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, textbox, special-characters

I'm looking for a solution (preferable jquery) to autocomplete only when the type in a special character. e.g:

"@name" lookup a name in the name list
"#tagname" lookup a value in the tag list
"$task" lookup a value from the task list

So if I want to assign a task to someone I type in: 
"@peter $sales #new #opportunity"

I hope some can help me. I suppose there is a jquery (or alike) plugin out there.

Comment: Nice one! I'd have to say. Still you should add whatever you've tried.

Comment: I have seen such solutions before, and I tried to find a jquery plugin that does something like that. I suppose there is a standard solution for ths.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on github: https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete (thanks yuku-t for writing this nice plugin!).

First include 
`<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/jquery.textcomplete.js"></script>`

The html

`<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" rows="4" style="position: relative; outline: 0px; background: transparent;"></textarea>`

The script

```
$('textarea').textcomplete([{
id: 'words',
match: /(^|\b)(\w{2,})$/,
search: function (term, callback) {
    var words = ['google', 'facebook', 'linkedin'];
    callback($.map(words, function (word) {
        return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
    }));
},
replace: function (word) {
    return word + ' ';
}
},
    { 
    id: 'names',
    mentions: ['peter','steven', 'jeffrey', 'paul'],
    match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
    search: function (term, callback) {
        callback($.map(this.mentions, function (mention) {
            return mention.indexOf(term) === 0 ? mention : null;
        }));
    },
    index: 1,
    replace: function (mention) {
        return '@' + mention + ' ';
    }
},
 { 
    id: 'tasks',
    tasks: ['invoice','call', 'email', 'put on hold'],
    match: /\B#(\w*)$/,
    search: function (term, callback) {
        callback($.map(this.tasks, function (task) {
            return task.indexOf(term) === 0 ? task : null;
        }));
    },
    index: 1,
    replace: function (task) {
        return '#' + task + ' ';
    }
}
                       ]);
```

Check http://codepen.io/jmdejongh/pen/EyKQrZ